AMPHP. How to make multiple asynchronous database requests?
use function Amp\async;
use Amp\Mysql\MysqlConfig;
use Amp\Mysql\MysqlConnectionPool;


$config = MysqlConfig::fromAuthority('ip', 'user', 'psw', 'table');
$db = new MysqlConnectionPool($config);


$db->query("INSERT INTO test (str) VALUES ('start')"); 


$future = async(function($db1) {

        $db1->query("INSERT INTO test (str) VALUES ('query 1')"); 
        $db1->query("INSERT INTO test (str) VALUES ('query 2')");  // <- it doesn't work. 

}, $db);


$db->query("INSERT INTO test (str) VALUES ('finish')"); 


//$result = $future->await();  //if remove the comment, 'query 2' will be inserted

I use the AMPHP library to work with the database.
I can't figure out why the second query doesn't work?
Do I need to run each database query separately?
async(fn($db1) => $db1->query("INSERT INTO test (str) VALUES ('query_1')"), $db);
async(fn($db1) => $db1->query("INSERT INTO test (str) VALUES ('query_2')"), $db);


Do you get an error, or the query is simply ignored?
